# cast Resource.Layout a int para inflate

Tags: android, c#, android-layout, xamarin

Estoy intentando implementar un método llamado `GetView()` que quiero utilizar para simplificar varios inflates que tengo que ir haciendo en mi App.

```
View GetView(Resource.Layout layout){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    View v = inflater.Inflate(layout, null, fallse);

    return v;


}
```

La cosa es que no sé como hacer que `layout` me valga para poder pasarle un argumento del tipo `Resource.Layout.NombreLayout`.

El error de compilación que me da es el siguiente.

> Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'App.Resource.Layout' a 'int'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes pasar un `int` al método pues es lo que requiere `Inflate`.

Por lo que quedaría así:

```
View GetView(int layout){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    View v = inflater.Inflate(layout, null, fallse);

    return v;


}
```

La llamada quedaría tal que así:

```
View vista = GetView(Resource.layout.tuLayout)
```

Credits to @Pikoh

Comment: grasias @Pikoh me sirbió